# How to calculate a GPA in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

The query should output the student's name and GPA.

The following tables are given:

section:

```
CREATE TABLE `Section` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Semester` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Room` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Instructor_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Course_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_Section_Instructor_idx` (`Instructor_ID`),
  KEY `fk_Section_Course1_idx` (`Course_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Section_Course1` FOREIGN KEY (`Course_ID`) REFERENCES `Course` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Section_Instructor` FOREIGN KEY (`Instructor_ID`) REFERENCES `Instructor` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `Section` VALUES (1,'Fa17','828',1,1),(2,'Fa17','828',2,3),(3,'Fa17','829',1,4),(4,'Fa17','829',4,5),(5,'Sp18','828',1,1),(6,'Sp18','829',1,2),(7,'Sp18','828',3,4),(8,'Sp18','828',4,5);
```

course:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Course`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `Course` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` text,
  `Units` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Course` VALUES (1,'CIS-15','Cloud Programming in Python',4),(2,'CIS-54','Relational Databases',4),(3,'CIS-81','Introduction to Networking',4),(4,'CIS-75','Introduction to Computer Security',3),(5,'CIS-90','Introduction to Linux',3);
```

registration:

```
 CREATE TABLE `Registration` (
  `Section_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Student_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Grade` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Section_ID`,`Student_ID`),
  KEY `fk_Section_has_Student_Student1_idx` (`Student_ID`),
  KEY `fk_Section_has_Student_Section1_idx` (`Section_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Section_has_Student_Section1` FOREIGN KEY (`Section_ID`) REFERENCES `Section` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Section_has_Student_Student1` FOREIGN KEY (`Student_ID`) REFERENCES `Student` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Registration` VALUES (1,1,4),(1,2,4),(2,2,3),(3,3,2),(4,1,3),(4,3,3),(5,3,NULL),(5,4,NULL),(6,1,NULL),(6,2,NULL),(7,1,NULL),(7,4,NULL),(8,2,NULL),(8,3,NULL);
```

student:

```
CREATE TABLE `Student` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Student` VALUES (1,'Steve Inskeep','steve@xyz.edu'),(2,'Rene Montaign','rene@xyz.edu'),(3,'David Green','david@xyz.edu'),(4,'Rachel Martin','rachel@xyz.edu');
```

I tried this code tried this and got nonsense output. I'm pretty lost

```
SELECT student.Name, (sum( registration.grade * course.units) /
    sum(course.units)
   ) as GPA FROM registration 

   join student on registration.student_ID = student.id join section on  section.ID = registration.section_ID
   join course on section.course_ID = course.ID
   group by registration.student_ID  ;
```

The GPA seems wrong because [image]

The returned result from @Barbaros Özhan 's suggestion as well as similar solutions of my own is :

'1', 'Steve Inskeep', '1.7857'

as the first returned row.

but clearly from eyeballing the registration table Student #1 does not have a 1.7857 GPA.

Edit: Answered by Gordon Linoff:

```
 select student.Name,
       (sum( registration.grade * course.units) /
        sum( case when registration.grade is not null then course.units end )
       ) as GPA
from registration  join 
     student 
     on registration.student_ID = student.id join
     section 
     on section.ID = registration.section_ID join
     course 
     on section.course_ID = course.ID
group by student.ID  ;
```

Comment: Does the grade have to be weighted by the course units?

Comment: @Nick That is unspecified.

Comment: @RichardMichaelLaboe . . . What do you mean by nonsense output?  The query looks ok.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just explained it in my edit.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expecteds results.. Also you would have to explain what a GPA is i assuming it a Grade Point Average?..

Comment: @RaymondNijland it is and sorry, this is my first computer anything class so I def don't know best practices for this sort of thing. Also, expected results not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have `NULL` grades . . . but you are counting the sections, so these are being treated as zeroes.

A slight adjust to your calculation will fix this:

```
select s.Name,
       (sum( r.grade * c.units) /
        sum( case when r.grade is not null then c.units end )
       ) as GPA
from registration r join 
     student s
     on r.student_ID = s.id join
     section se
     on se.ID = r.section_ID join
     course c
     on se.course_ID = c.ID
group by s.student_ID  ;
```

Comment: Wow sweet! Did not know how to handle those nulls or about case when at all! Thanks! I slightly edited your code to:  select student.Name,
       (sum( registration.grade * course.units) /
        sum( case when registration.grade is not null then course.units end )
       ) as GPA
from registration  join 
     student 
     on registration.student_ID = student.id join
     section 
     on section.ID = registration.section_ID join
     course 
     on section.course_ID = course.ID
group by student.ID  ;   but yeah this totally worked

Comment: @RichardMichaelLaboe . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  It was the first answer that pointed out the issue in your calculation and how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry! I'm new and thought I could mark more than one person as having answered. Mb! correction applied

Answer (score 1):

Given that a student gets a grade per section, I don't think you need the `Section` and `Course` tables in your query (although without seeing sample data, it's hard to be certain). This should work:

```
SELECT s.Name, COALESCE(SUM(r.Grade) / COUNT(r.Grade), 0) AS GPA
FROM student s
JOIN registration r ON r.Student_ID = s.ID
GROUP BY s.Name
```

Output

```
Name            GPA
David Green     2.5
Rachel Martin   0
Rene Montaign   3.5
Steve Inskeep   3.5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rFqju5Nr8Hz7eP1XrwUmpt/1)

If you are required to weight grades according to course units then you need to sum the multiplication of the grade by the units and then divide by the sum of the units, taking care to *only* sum the course units where there is a valid grade:

```
SELECT s.Name, 
       ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(r.Grade * c.Units) / SUM(CASE WHEN r.Grade IS NOT NULL THEN c.Units ELSE 0 END), 0), 2) AS GPA
FROM Student s
JOIN Registration r ON r.Student_ID = s.ID
JOIN Section x ON x.ID = r.Section_ID
JOIN Course c ON c.ID = x.Course_ID
GROUP BY s.Name;
```

Output:

```
Name            GPA
David Green     2.5
Rachel Martin   0
Rene Montaign   3.5
Steve Inskeep   3.57
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rFqju5Nr8Hz7eP1XrwUmpt/2)

Comment: Thanks! this also answered the question. I had not previously heard of the coalesce function. @GordonLinoff had a solution that did not need to use the round or coalesce functions and returned the same output. When are those necessary?

Comment: @RichardMichaelLaboe my solution also doesn't **require** use of `COALESCE` or `ROUND`. `COALESCE` is used to convert what would otherwise be a `NULL` value for `Rachel Martin` to a 0, so if you're happy to have `NULL` values you can remove that, and the `ROUND` is because in the weighted GPA query, the result for `Steve Inskeep` would come out as 3.5714 and I thought it would be more useful to have it as 3.57 since GPA is usually only expressed to 2 decimal places. To see the results without `COALESCE` and `ROUND` see this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rFqju5Nr8Hz7eP1XrwUmpt/3

Comment: Very Cool! Thanks a ton for explaining that to me!  Those are great points.

Comment: @RichardMichaelLaboe no worries, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can join your tables as below :

```
select s.ID, s.Name,  
       sum( r.grade * c.Units ) / sum(c.Units) as GPA
  from student s
  left join registration r on r.Student_ID = s.ID
  left join section sc on sc.ID = r.Section_ID
  left join course c on c.ID = sc.Course_ID 
 group by s.ID, s.Name
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d224d3a1f72f3c32aa26631dd2921aed)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your help. The solution you gave doesn't seem accurate as I just explained in my edit. I'm not sure why either.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining to student ID from registration table, but you haven't selected it from registration table in order to join to it.  Try adding student ID to the selection from registration table.

Then you are joining course table to section table, but section table has not been joined yet.  Invalid operation, you need to join to section first before you can join from section to course.

There could be other troubles, but start from here.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT AVG(gpa) FROM ASFANDYAR KHAN
Select * From ASFANDYAR KHAN
WHERE GPA>(select AVG(GPA) FROM    ASFANDYAR KHAN)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).